# Run custom shell script through udev

Tags: linux, bash, shell, udev

I'm trying to make an udev rule that'll play sound upon connecting the charger. The rule seems to work fine except I can not get the shell script to run. This is my udev rule:

```
$cat 01-mru-battery-oncharger.rules 
# Rule to play sound when charger 
(AC0) is plugged in

SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", 
ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_NAME}=="AC0", 
ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1", 
RUN+="/usr/local/bin/play_sound_charger_connected.sh"
```

And this is the script. The /usr/local/bin has a symlink to the original script in my home directory (~/.customization/shell-scripts)

```
$cat .customization/shell- 
scripts/play_sound_charger_connected.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/ffplay /home/xt/Music/System/Nothing\ Charging\ Sound.mp3 -nodisp -nostats -autoexit -hide_banner
```

When I run udev test it seems to trigger the rule but the script doesn't work --

```
AC0: /etc/udev/rules.d/01-mru-battery-oncharger.rules:3 RUN '/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/play_sound_charger_connected.sh' 
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC0
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=AC0
POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE=Mains
POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE=1
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=power_supply
USEC_INITIALIZED=827516597
run: '/usr/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/play_sound_charger_connected.sh'
```

I highly appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!!!